# What does this array created by KMeans represent?

Tags: clustering, k-means

[KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) is a common clustering algorithm. However, I am not clear about the steps involved.

I am using commonly used iris dataset, which has 4 numeric features and 1 Species column.

```
print(irisdf.head())
# output: 
     SL    SW    PL    PW Species
0 5.100 3.500 1.400 0.200  setosa
1 4.900 3.000 1.400 0.200  setosa
2 4.700 3.200 1.300 0.200  setosa
3 4.600 3.100 1.500 0.200  setosa
4 5.000 3.600 1.400 0.200  setosa
```

The species column is not used here:

```
myarray = irisdf.iloc[:,:4].values
print(myarray[:5,:])
# output: 
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]]
```

I am using scikit-learn software to perform KMeans clustering:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
transformed_array = kmeans.fit_transform(myarray)
```

The transformed array returned by kmeans fit_transform function has 3 columns and 150 rows (as many rows as in iris data). Top 5 rows of the transformed array are as follows:

```
print(transformed_array[:5,:])
# output: 
[[5.0595416  0.14135063 3.41925061]
 [5.11494335 0.44763825 3.39857426]
 [5.27935534 0.4171091  3.56935666]
 [5.15358977 0.52533799 3.42240962]
 [5.10433388 0.18862662 3.46726403]]
```

I want to understand what this array returned by fit_transform function of KMeans represent. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does documentation for that program exist?

Comment: The result of kmeans should be a cluster label for each data point. What is "fit_transform" expected to do? Presumably this is not the right function for the clustering job, but does something else.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to know.

Comment: @ttnphns I have linked the documentation in question above (on first word). It says this function is to "Compute clustering and transform X to cluster-distance space." I want to understand what does this mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py#L749):

```
def transform(self, X):
    """Transform X to a cluster-distance space.
    In the new space, each dimension is the distance to the cluster
    centers.  Note that even if X is sparse, the array returned by
    `transform` will typically be dense.
```

So it is the euclidean distance to each center, we can calculate this for the first few entries. First the data:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
myarray = iris.data

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

import numpy as np

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
transformed_array = kmeans.fit_transform(myarray)
```

Euclidean distance function:

```
def euclid(a,b):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((a-b)**2))
```

The transformed matrix, first few entries:

```
kmeans.transform(myarray)[:3]

array([[5.0595416 , 0.14135063, 3.41925061],
       [5.11494335, 0.44763825, 3.39857426],
       [5.27935534, 0.4171091 , 3.56935666]])
```

The euclidean distance calculation for the first few entries:

```
[euclid(j,i) for i in kmeans.cluster_centers_] for j in myarray[:3]]

[[5.05954160165094, 0.1413506278726769, 3.4192506070540882],
 [5.11494334566502, 0.44763824680203546, 3.398574255758474],
 [5.2793553392231445, 0.4171090984382863, 3.5693566607869642]]
```